# How to query by age in Mongodb?

Tags: date, mongodb, field

If I have a dob (date of birth) field in MongoDB, how can I query all records where date of birth is less than 1/1/1990 (it's a string) or less than a certain age?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either store the data as Date() object or as string in ISO format. In both cases you can use the standard $gt or $lt operators.

Answer (score 6):

You can store your DOB dates in ISO format - yyyymmdd - as a simple number, i.e.

```
db.col.insert( { dob: 19910412 } )
db.col.insert( { dob: 19900708 } )
db.col.insert( { dob: 19880511 } )
db.col.insert( { dob: 19870225 } )
```

Then, to find all the dates before a particular date, do this:

```
db.col.find( { dob: { $lt: 19900101 } } )
```

Adding an index to this field will speed up these queries:

```
db.col.ensureIndex( { dob: 1 } )
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest storing a 'real' date object rather than a string. You may then use the usual comparison operators. If you cannot do that, an alternative would be storing an age integer. The latter is less useful as it must be updated every year but it's worth considering.

**EDIT:** An alternative that will allow you to work with your existing data would be to pass a match function to collection.find(). Obviously this has performance implications as the function must be evaluated for each object in the collection. See [$where docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-JavascriptExpressionsand%7B%7B%24where%7D%7D). For example...

```
var date =  function() {
    return new Date(this.dob) < new Date('1/1/1990');
}

db.mycollection.find(date);
```

Comment: You can also store dates as string using ISO format. Comparison against ISO dates will work perfectly since comparison follows lexicographical ordering..

Comment: @Sentinel Useful to know. The OP isn't storing dates in that way though.